# Cannot create Spark Phoenix DataFrames

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am trying to load data from Apache Phoenix into a Spark DataFrame.

I have been able to successfully create an RDD with the following code:

```scala
val sc = new SparkContext("local", "phoenix-test")
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

val foo: RDD[Map[String, AnyRef]] = sc.phoenixTableAsRDD(
    table   = "FOO", 
    columns = Seq("ID", "MESSAGE_EPOCH", "MESSAGE_VALUE"), 
    zkUrl   = Some("<zk-ip-address>:2181:/hbase-unsecure"))

foo.collect().foreach(x => println(x))
```

However I have not been so lucky trying to create a DataFrame. My current attempt is:

```scala
val sc = new SparkContext("local", "phoenix-test")
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

val df = sqlContext.phoenixTableAsDataFrame(
    table   = "FOO", 
    columns = Seq("ID", "MESSAGE_EPOCH", "MESSAGE_VALUE"), 
    zkUrl   = Some("<zk-ip-address>:2181:/hbase-unsecure"))

df.select(df("ID")).show
```

Unfortunately the above code results in a ClassCastException:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericMutableRow cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.Row
```

I am still very new to spark. If anyone can help it would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Although you haven't mentioned your spark version and details of the exception...

***Please see [PHOENIX-2287 which is fixed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PHOENIX-2287), which says***

**Environment: HBase 1.1.1 running in standalone mode on OS X ***

**Spark 1.5.0 Phoenix 4.5.2**

> Josh Mahonin added a comment - 23/Sep/15 17:56 Updated patch adds
>   support for Spark 1.5.0, and is backwards compatible back down to
>   1.3.0 (manually tested, Spark version profiles may be worth looking at in the future) In 1.5.0, they've gone and explicitly hidden the
>   `GenericMutableRow` data structure. Fortunately, we are able to the
>   external-facing '`Row`' data type, which is backwards compatible, and
>   should remain compatible in future releases as well. As part of the
>   update, Spark SQL deprecated a constructor on their '`DecimalType`'.
>   In updating this, I exposed a new issue, which is that we don't
>   carry-forward the precision and scale of the underlying Decimal type
>   through to Spark. For now I've set it to use the Spark defaults, but
>   I'll create another issue for that specifically. I've included an
>   ignored integration test in this patch as well.

Comment: you are okay with my answer, pls. vote-up ,"accepted-by-owner" which helps to other users as a pointer